# How to change OpenShift's default grouping on a project's Overview Dashboard?

Tags: openshift, dashboard, openshift-origin

by default when you login to OpenShift or OKD and you open a project, on the left-side you have an Overview button at the top of the menu.

Pressing that button will show you all DeploymentConfigs, StatefulSets, Provisioned services and etc. but unfortunately, it groups them like so:

```
Application
<nameOfDeploymentConfig>

Application
<nameOfSecondDeploymentConfig>

Application
<nameOfNthDeploymentConfig>
```

I am searching for a way to add a label or something, to have them grouped like:

```
MyCustomLabel (e.g. Databases)
<nameOfDeploymentConfig>
<nameOfDeploymentConfig2>
<NameOfNthDeploymentConfig>
```

As it will make it much more readable.

Comment: They should be grouped based on the `app` label

Comment: Hi @WillGordon, indeed they are, but is there a way to add another label or can you only change the `APP` label in order to organize them?

Comment: AFAIK, it is only the `app` label. You could try requesting an RFE at https://github.com/openshift/origin-web-console/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Will Gordon pointed out, there is no other way to group the pods in the 3.X Openshift UI.